# multiplayer game with bluetooth [iphone]

Tags: iphone

i am doing a multiplayer game with bluetooth, currently i am able to connect one iphone to another via picker. Now the problem is that how can i make two phones play with one another with the same screen synchronize and who play which character?

I'm very new to this, is there any simple bluetooth games out there which i can get? Really need help with this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has a Bluetooth game sample online. Just check their examples in the [iPhone Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/iphone).

Answer (score 2):

Apple's GameKit sample [GKTank](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GKTank/index.html) will be very helpful to you. Note you will need to be logged in to your developer account to use the link.

Comment: page has been removed! please edit your answer with latest link.