# how can I send and recieve data using bluetooth in iphone without any permission?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I want to develop an app for iphone, which should be installed on both devices, 
the device will get particular data from iphone(which has same data), without any permission and acceptance from those iphone which has that app installed and running status,,,

how can I implement such idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to bypass peering permission for bluetooth devices in iphone programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114967/how-to-bypass-peering-permission-for-bluetooth-devices-in-iphone-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is connect two iOS devices via Bluetooth, check out apple's example programs for this:

[multiplayer game with bluetooth [iphone]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2092270/2915)

If you are trying to get an iOS device to talk to a serial Bluetooth device, the answer is that you have to enter apple's hardware development program to do so.

There are workarounds, including jail breaking, but you'll have to be more specific about your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that you probably can't.

*If* Bluetooth is already manually enabled, *and* you have gotten some manner of blank check from the user, them *maybe* you can "spontaneously" send data when some other device is sensed.

Comment: @Mr Williham, I want security and only want to sent and recieve amonst particular device which has installed such app, not all,,,,